# how to remove entry meta from wordpress archive category and change its display

Tags: posts, templates

I'm working with the Bootstrap Child Theme on WordPress. My problem is that I want to remove the entry meta - like posted on date by admin - and also want to change the display of all these posts, but I'm unable to find the right file to edit. I have commented this code in `content-single.php` but nothing seems to be happening:

```
<header class="page-header">
    <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
    <?php /*?><div class="entry-meta"><?php the_bootstrap_posted_on(); ?></div><?php */?><!-- .entry-meta -->
</header>
```

Here is a link to my category archive: http://graavaa.com/category/travertine/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you didn't actually comment out anything in your edits.

When you added `<?php /* ?>`, you're creating a PHP comment just fine, but then closing the PHP tag, which some interpreters will cause to close the comments as well.

Instead, either, wrap the HTML you want eliminated in *HTML comments* or just delete it entirely:

```
<header class="page-header">
    <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
    <!--<div class="entry-meta"><?php the_bootstrap_posted_on(); ?></div>--><!-- .entry-meta -->
</header>
```

By wrapping the markup in an HTML comment, it will still render to the page source, but won't actually be rendered by the browser. Eventually, though, you should *still* just delete the line so there isn't unnecessary markup sent as output.

Just be careful with HTML comments, because they don't nest:

```
<!--<div class="entry-meta"><?php the_bootstrap_posted_on(); ?></div><!-- .entry-meta -->-->
```

The above code looks like it would comment out the entire block, unfortunately the extra `-->` at the end will *be printed as plain text* to the browser. Just use comments like this judiciously and, as I already suggested, delete the commented-out lines when you're done testing.

Beyond this, I would look for any other references to `class="entry-meta"` in other template files within the theme and, similarly, comment them out (or delete them).